# Extracting variance components from GLMM

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, variance

There are many ways to extract variance components from linear mixed-effect models (LME), but I failed to decide which code is proper to extract variance components from a generalized linear mixed-effect model (GLMM).

I have data in the following format, and I try to understand which factor explains more variance in data in comparison to the other, and specifically, I need to conduct a variance component analysis.

```
data <- rbind(data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),      
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "no", factor2 = "h"),
     data.frame(data = "1", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "w"),
     data.frame(data = "0", factor1 = "yes", factor2 = "h"))
```

### with `glmer`

By using the suggested method in lme4 (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html);

```
library(lme4)
mod1 <- glmer(data~(1|factor1) +(1|factor2), family = binomial, data = data)
summary(mod1)
```

I obtained such a result about variances for a dataset (let's call *dataset1*);

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name       Variance Std.Dev.
 factor1 (Intercept) 0.001584 0.0398  
 factor2 (Intercept) 0.354064 0.5950
```

and for another dataset (i.e. *dataset2*), I obtained;

```
Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 factor1 (Intercept) 0.7770   0.8815  
 factor2 (Intercept) 0.2811   0.5302
```

I was expecting that variance values factor1+factor2+residual=1.0, but in the second case, it had already exceeded 1.0 with two factors. So, I suppose that in GLMMs, we can not interpret these variance values as exact "variance components" as we do in LMEs.

### with `getME` function

By using `getME` fuction in lme4 for *dataset1*,

```
library(lme4)
mod1 <- glmer(data~(1|factor1) +(1|factor2), family = binomial, data = data)
getME(mod1, "theta")^2
```

I obtained the completely same results above.

### with `glmm`

By using `glmm` fuction in glmm package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmm/index.html), when I run

```
library(glmm)
m <- 1000
data$data <- ifelse(data$data=="1", 1, 0)
mod1 <- glmm(data~1, random=list(~1+factor1, ~1+factor2), varcomps.names=c("factor1", "factor2"), data=data, family.glmm=binomial.glmm, m=m, debug=TRUE)
varcomps(mod1)
```

then, I got (for *dataset1*)

```
     factor1      factor2
8.581048e-06 3.634846e-01
```

which are different values, but saying the same thing with the codes in lme4 (I mean, factor2>factor1).

and for *dataset2*

```
  factor1   factor2
0.7427292 0.5572225
```

this result is a  bit more different than the analysis done with the codes in lme4 with *dataset2* (I mean, factor1 seems to explain more, but still factor1>factor2).

My **first question** is, even the variance values I obtained are not exact "variance components", can we use these values for a comparison between factor1 and factor2?

My **second question** is, which of these codes are proper to perform such an analysis, and is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If I run the first  of your code chunks with the data provided then I get completely different estimates, and also this warning: `convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular`

Comment: Sure, the data I provided here just a small example. The real data include more than a thousand raws.

Comment: for your real data, are there only two levels in each of the grouping variables?

Comment: for factor 1, there are always two levels (yes/no); for factor 2 in some cases two levels, but in some cases more than two levels (up to 8 levels). I just put the example data here to show the simplest one.